# run a .bat file without being logged in to windows account

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-8.1, dial-up, pppoe

I would like to connect my dial up broadband pppoe when my system starts without logging into my account on windows 8.1, I have successfully running some other programs like team viewer apache, mysql, filezilla server using windows task scheduler. SO i have also created a .bat file using rasdial to connect my dialup connection the code is

```
rasdial connection_name username pass
rasdial connection_name /d
rasdial connection_name username pass
```

this works fine when I double click on it but it is not working with windows task scheduler but why?